# File not uploaded in PHP tmp/php error

Tags: php

I have a php script which uploads 5 attachment files in 5 directories from for data.

The form has the property `enctype="multipart/form-data"

```
<input type="file" name="file_photo" id="file_photo">
```

My PHP Script is:

```
$filename_p = $_FILES["file_photo"]["name"];
$file_basename_p = substr($filename_p, 0, strripos($filename_p, '.')); // get file extention
$file_ext_p = substr($filename_p, strripos($filename_p, '.')); // get file name
$newfilename_p = $cname . "_" . $file_basename_p . $file_ext_p;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_photo"]["tmp_name"], "Uploads/photo/" . $newfilename_p);
```

The `Uploads/photo/` directory has permission: `755`

The File is NOT being uploaded in the Directory `Uploads/photo/`

The output of `print_r($_FILES);` is:

```
Array ( [file_photo] => Array ( [name] => IICB-logo (1).jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpFkYJgw [error] => 0 [size] => 12857 )
```

`php.ini` has `upload_max_filesize = 200M` and `max_file_uploads = 200`

What should I do?

Comment: give the full path to uploads, the problem is with the path, it cannot locate the path

Comment: Given the full path. i.e. `/var/www/html/iicb/sdp/Uploads/photo/` does not help.

Comment: Is there a warning issued by move_uploaded_file? Usually when it cannot move a file and the function returns false, it also generates a warning

Comment: does the user has permission to write files? and try to give 777 permission once just to check if it helps

Comment: @mighTY The Warning message is: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(/var/www/html/iicb/sdp/Uploads/photo/Akash Gupta_IICB-logo (1).jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/iicb/sdp/registration.php on line 48`

Comment: try:  sudo chown -R [your_user]:[your_user] Uploads/ - where your_user is the user under which php runs.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the owner of `Uploads/photo/` is the same as the one who run php. If not change owner of the directory: `chown [user] Uploads/photo/`. Assuming you have access to the command line.

Comment: The user of PHP and the directories are same.